# How to start primary_key from some value?

Tags: yii2

I need to start primary_key index from e.g. 1000. How can I do it in migration? Or maybe in a model (but as I understand yii2 doesn't know anything about what id row will have)?

Comment: Is migration is fresh? You can execute raw query in migration using `$this->execute('Increment pk query')`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:
create a new migration and in up function add:

```
public function safeUp()
{
    $this->execute("ALTER TABLE {table_name} AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;");
}
```